# How can I registrate users in my my google actions webhook?

Tags: javascript, authentication, actions-on-google

I am trying to allow users to register by voice when they use my Google action. How can I do it?

I have tried to use Account linking with Google Sign-In using the Client ID, but I do not know how to collect the user data in my webhook.

Looking for information I found that:

```
app.intent("Show User Profile", conv => {
  const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
  if (payload) {

    const userId = payload.aud;
    const name = payload.name;
    const givenName = payload.given_name;
    const familyName = payload.family_name;
    const email = payload.email;
    const emailVerified = payload.email_verified;
    const picture = payload.picture;

.....
```

But I have implemented my intents in the following way and I can't use the conv parameter:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  async function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome`);
      ...
  }
   . . . 

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I need to get the user information as the case above but using my variable agent instead of conv

Thanks all of you

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, you seem to be using the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library. You cannot use this library to do Google Sign-In. You will need to switch over to the [`actions-on-google`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) library, which has the pattern in the first snippet.